# How does Google display a site in different languages?

Tags: localization, fonts

Can someone please let me know if it is possible to display a site in a language (other than English say Chinese) even if the user's system doesn't have that font (Chinese font)? 
I've seen that in Google. Even if I have the font, still I can see the site in that language. But there are certain sites which can be read only if the font is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is far from being clear but I suspect that you are interested about [CSS3 downloadabel fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#src-desc) and specially about the fonts hosted by Google at http://www.google.com/webfonts

So if you want to maximize the visibility of Unicode text in your HTML application you must **be sure that you serve `UTF-8` encoded pages** and that your `CSS` specifies a large set of fonts instead and always keep the fallback generic font last:

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

In addition you may want to add a CSS3 downloadable font, but from my experience this is not going to help because most browsers will not be able to take advantage of it, especially the ones running on systems with "bad" fonts.

Mainly, you do not care so much, I work on internationalization field so I do have more than average fonts installed on my systems and I remember seeing boxes for some weird languages.

Now if you respect the above recommendations and still have some specific problems, please open a new question and we'll find a way to help you.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I've modified the question. It is not about CSS3 fonts. It is about how to display a website in a particular language (ex. Chinese) even if the user's system doesn't have that font installed.

Comment: Thank you so much sorion for the help.This was very useful. Even we are planning to provide multiple language support for our application.

Comment: There are certain sites whose supported encoding is ISO-8859-1 and written in some local language. This site can be properly viewed in IE but not in Mozilla. But if you install the font, you can view that in Mozilla also? I thought font is just a visual representation of a character in the character set. So if that character is not there in the set, how can installing the font help?

Comment: @Apps please give clear examples, from your last message I suspect the IE is doing some non standard tricks and overrides the encoding.

Comment: If you visit manoramaonline.com in IE, you will be able to see the content properly, whereas in Firefox you will not see that. Now when I install the font, it works fine. (it is available under "Unable to Read?" section in that site). character is not there in the set, how can installing the font help?

Comment: Dude, this site is borken, they have a lot to lean! By change IE did content auto detection instead of using the wrong encoding specified in file header. This in not a quality of IE, it just broke the W3C specification.

Answer (score 2):

In all the google sites google uses Unicode (UTF-8, UTF-16) fonts which are by default supported by most of the browsers

You can use unicode in your multi language site, This doesn't need any fonts to be installed

```
 e.g.  सुस्वागतम, 为鄂伦春哦么
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/
Section 4.3 shows that you can point to an external location for the font.